# Is there a Stack Exchange site for practicing questions or quizzes?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am currently learning [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) and as my understanding of Webdriver and Server continues to improve, I would like to put what I've learnt so far to the test by working on some real life interview questions, tests, and exercises.

Googling for "Selenium practice tests" only brings up some sites on which I can play around with some elements and some MCQs.

Is there any Stack Exchange site for this purpose? If not, can someone please suggest some questions, tasks, and exercises for me to help me improve my understanding of Selenium?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Journeyman Geek has answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316413/179419) there is no Stack Exchange site that has a set of practice tests you can do. However... [as I wrote in 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254908/458741), I think it's still possible to use Stack Exchange for this purpose.

> ... if I have one bit of advice for someone who honestly wants to learn
>   something here it's: answer everything. I do *not* mean click "Post
>   Your Answer". I mean attempt to answer everything within a problem
>   domain that you have some experience.
>
> As you post check everyone else's answer and assess it against your
>   understanding of the question. If you're completely wrong then it
>   doesn't matter and you don't need to post. If you're correct, or if
>   everyone else is completely wrong (it happens!) then post...

You're not doing tests, interview questions or exercises, true. You're investigating and solving real world problems that people are currently facing. You can learn a huge amount this way.

It's likely if you're starting out that someone has posted a better answer than you. That's fine, you have just learnt something. If there's no better answer (and you have working **code**) you can ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for someone to assess how it could be improved. If you want to check whether the testing strategies you're using in your answer are correct there's [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Personally, I much prefer the real world over contrived examples. YMMV.

Comment: Hah. That is true, and something I totally missed. You get so much more posting 
good answers imo

Answer (score 2):

As is often the case - well the sort of open ended "test my skills" sites is *often* not a good fit for SE. The SE platform's really good at helping people find solutions to problems. What you're looking for is *problems to solve*.

> If not, can someone please suggest some questions/tasks/excercises for me to help me improve my understanding of Selenium ?

That bit's the classic "learning material recommendation" - which nearly all sites have as a closing reason.

In a nutshell - no, and its pretty unlikely we'd be able to fit this into the SE model without massive mental gymnastics of how we do Q&A